# Pure-FTPd sending right pasv response, but wrong IP received

Tags: linux, networking, ftp

I started my ftp server with `pure-ftpd -l puredb:/etc/pure-ftpd/pureftpd.pdb -E -j -R -P 67.68.xxx.xx -s -A -j -Z -H -4 -E -R -G -X -x -d -d -U 113:000  -p 30000:30009 -c 50 -C 5`

In my Pure-FTPd log file, I have:

`[DEBUG] Command [pasv] []
227 Entering Passive Mode (67,68,xxx,xx,117,54)`

Hovever, my ftp client receive this:

`---> PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,2,23,231,6)
ftp: connect: No route to host`

Why is this happening and how could I receive the right IP address? Thank you.

Comment: So your FTP server is not on your local network, right? What device is at 192.168.2.23?

Comment: It is a public ftp server that I test remotely. 192.168.2.23 does not exist. Actually, the FTP server doesn't have any interface in 192.168

Comment: Try encrypting the FTP connection. It’s probably some FTP NAT helper running amok.

Comment: Encrypting the connection worked. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielB you may add your solution as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because FTP sends IP addresses and ports *inside* messages like this (not just in the packet headers), it is not a NAT-friendly protocol.

Because of this, NAT gateways often have special code to handle FTP. This code is known as an FTP "Application-Layer Gateway", or ALG. FTP ALGs look for messages like the PASV command and re-write the IP address to represent the public IP address of the NAT gateway, in order to make the communication work.

If your FTP client is behind a NAT gateway and your FTP server is not, then using passive mode is a way to work around a bad NAT gateway that doesn't have an FTP ALG.

If your FTP client is **NOT** behind a NAT gateway but your FTP server **IS**, then you can use normal active FTP without a problem, but Passive Mode would actually break in this case if the NAT gateway in front of the FTP server doesn't have a good FTP ALG. Many NAT gateways have half-broken FTP ALGs that only make active FTP work for FTP clients behind the NAT, but don't handle the "FTP **server** behind the NAT" case. Apparently a lot of NAT gateway vendors don't think about or care about the server-behind-the-NAT case.

If both your FTP client and your FTP server are each behind separate NAT gateways that don't have FTP ALGs, then active FTP will be blocked by the client's NAT **and** passive FTP will be blocked by the server's NAT, so you just can't do plain FTP at all in that case, and will need to set up some kind of tunnel or other workaround. Switching to encrypted FTP will work because encrypted FTP protocols were developed after NAT gateways were common, and the authors knew that a NAT gateway wouldn't be able to see or mess with the internals of the protocol, so they had to design it to work in all the various NAT scenarios.

Comment: “Because FTP sends IP addresses and ports inside messages like this (not just in the packet headers), it is not a NAT-friendly protocol.” – The problem is actually with the dynamic data connections. Having to send addresses and ports is just a result of that.

Comment: Thank you @Spiff for the detailed explanation. Both my client and my server were behind separated NAT, so I encrypted the connection and it works.